# Displaying search results on infinite scroll in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, search, laravel, infinite-scroll

I am trying to figure how to display the search results on infinite scroll (only 8 results at a time). I am able to get an array of the results and the var_dump() of the array results looks something like this :

```
arrray (size 21)
 0 =>
   object(stdClass)
     id => int 18
     image => string 'images/product-list/pro1-list.jpg'
     brand_name => string 'XYZ'
 1 =>
   object(stdClass)
     id => int 19
     image => string 'images/product-list/pro2-list.jpg'
     brand_name => string 'ABC'
 2 =>
   object(stdClass)
     id => int 18
     image => string 'images/product-list/pro3-list.jpg'
     brand_name => string 'LMN'

 ... and so on
```

The results are being returned from a controller to the blade template as $output

```
@foreach($output as $res)
   <div class="pro_img">
     <a href="">{{$res->image}}</a><br/>
   </div>
   <div class="brand">
     <a href="">{{$res->brand_name}}</a><br/>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

I am able to get all the 21 results displayed but how to display them as only 8 products at a time and display the next 8 on page scroll ? I am kinda new to laravel and would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use javascript to detect their scroll position and show or load next results accordingly.  If there is a large amount of items, AJAX requests can be used to also load more results.

Answer (score 1):

use laravel pagination infinite scroll [link](http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/tutorials/php/laravel-4-pagination-with-infinite-scroll-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use this [plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) who is advise in laravel forum.